# JPQL select based on non null dto values

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

Hi everyone I am using spring JPA and I am trying to filter my query result based on nonnull DTO field values.

The reason is every time I have different DTO fields and I should get books based on just the existing fields or in other words the nonnull fields.

My DB table is books and I have the following DTO for it

```
public class BookDTO {
private String name;
private String title;
private String isbn;
private String author;
private int pages;
private String size;
}
```

I searched over the web but I didn't find a solution for this kind of issue anyway to achieve this using Spring JPQL

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using JpaSpecificationExecutor ([scroll down to section 5](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries)

This way you can programmatically define what fields are you going to add to your where clause, like this .:

```
(Specification<Book>) (book, cq, cb) ->
  cb.and(
    // You can dynamically construct that array of predicates based on which fields are set in the form
    cb.like(book.get("author"), "%" + author + "%"),
    cb.like(book.get("title"), "%" + title + "%")
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

one alternative is to use Spring Data JPA Specification.

With that you can create your criteria search for the fields that are present.

```
public Predicate toPredicate
      (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
 
        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
              root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        } 
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
            return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
              root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        } 
        else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return builder.like(
                  root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } else {
                return builder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

reference: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Answer (score 0):

You can try Example query.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-examples

Example queries
The class org.hibernate.criterion.Example allows you to construct a query criterion from a given instance.

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.setSex('F');
cat.setColor(Color.BLACK);
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .list();
```

Version properties, identifiers and associations are ignored. By default, null valued properties are excluded.

You can adjust how the Example is applied.

```
Example example = Example.create(cat)
    .excludeZeroes()           //exclude zero valued properties
    .excludeProperty("color")  //exclude the property named "color"
    .ignoreCase()              //perform case insensitive string comparisons
    .enableLike();             //use like for string comparisons
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add(example)
    .list();
```

You can even use examples to place criteria upon associated objects.

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .add( Example.create(cat) )
    .createCriteria("mate")
        .add( Example.create( cat.getMate() ) )
    .list();
```